# How do I create line breaks when passing a string into codeigniter's download helper

Tags: codeigniter, download, helper, line-breaks

How do I create line breaks when passing a string into codeigniter's download helper. I have tried the code below which succesfully downloads the file and the string but it just outputs directly the `\r\n` rather than converting them into new lines. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
$reportOutput = '';

foreach($data['displayPostingRecords'] as $result)
{
$reportOutput .=  rawurldecode($result['wpPostlink']).' \r\n ';
}

//download the file..
$fileName = 'report-articleBatchID-'.$articleBatchID.'.txt';
$this->load->helper('download');
force_download($fileName, $reportOutput);
```

Comment: sorry my first answer was bad, i've been looking at code too much today XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry long day... change the single tick quotes to regular quotes and that'll fix your problem.

```
$reportOutput = '';

foreach($data['displayPostingRecords'] as $result)
{
$reportOutput .=  rawurldecode($result['wpPostlink']) . "\r\n";
}

//download the file..
$fileName = 'report-articleBatchID-'.$articleBatchID.'.txt';
$this->load->helper('download');
force_download($fileName, $reportOutput);
```